# How to get list of all Kafka topics in a cluster along with the partition number available for topics and unique partitions number

Tags: bash, unix, apache-kafka

How to get list of all Kafka topics in a cluster along with the partition number available for topics and unique partitions number also. Java code or cli commands would be appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

To list all kafka topics:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181,localhost:2182
```

To list all of the partitions of a particular topic you need to run the following (the count of partitions is listed as `PartitionCount`):

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181,localhost:2182 --topic myTopic

Topic:myTopic        PartitionCount:4        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
        Topic: myTopic       Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
        Topic: myTopic       Partition: 1    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
        Topic: myTopic       Partition: 2    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
        Topic: myTopic       Partition: 3    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
```

Comment: Actually I am working on Kafka-rebalancing and suppose I have 100 topics so I want partitions for all 100 topics. I can't execute it for 100 topics so I want something that work here. and also the total partitions and some command to get the unique leader count for each topic.

Comment: Use a bash script.

Comment: can you please help with the bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka topic list and detail command can be combined together to achieve the result. Below is a sample bash script file that can be used to list all the topics with partition count.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while [[ "$#" > 0 ]]; do case $1 in
  -i|--zookeeper_ip) ZOOKEEPER_IP="$2"; shift;shift;;
  *) usage "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; shift; shift;;
esac; done

echo "Zookeepr IP: $ZOOKEEPER_IP"

TOPICS=$(kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper ${ZOOKEEPER_IP}:2181)

for TOPIC in ${TOPICS}; do
  TOPIC_DETAIL=$(kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper ${ZOOKEEPER_IP}:2181 --topic ${TOPIC} --describe |  grep -i "config" | column -t)

  echo ${TOPIC_DETAIL} | awk '{print $2, $4}'
done
```

Save the above file as a bash script e.g. `get-topics-partition.sh` and run with the following command.

`./get-topics-partition.sh -i <kafka_zookeeper_ip_without_port>`

**NOTE:** Don't forget to give appropriate permission to run the file.
E.g. `chmod +x get-topics-partition.sh`